# Pass primary key in success_url in Delete Class view in django

Tags: django, request, primary-key, reverse, attributeerror

I have a **Post** model in my models.py

In  templates, **postdescripition.html**, I have below code for delete button, In postdescription.html, I referred post object

```
<a class=type="submit" href="{% url 'delete' pk=post.id %}" >Delete </a>
```

In urls.py

```
path('posts/<int:pk>/delete',views.Delete_Post.as_view(), name = 'delete') ,
```

In views.py

```
class Delete_Post(DeleteView):
     model = Post
     template_name = 'dlt.html'
     # dlt.html have an confirmation button
     # success_url= '/profile/1' -> working 
     #i want 1 to should be replaced by user id
     # reverse_lazy('posts') -> working
     #success_url = reverse_lazy('profile/pk=id')-> not working
      success_url= "/posts/"
```

After deletion I want to redirect to that user profile page, so I need that user.id.., to pass into the view after deletion , I am using "/posts/" in   success_url  which redirects me to all posts, that's working fine

urls.py

```
  path('profile/<pk>/', views.Profile, name='profile'),
```

But to get id, I tried

1. request.user.id inside 'Delete_Post' class view

`request is not defined error`

2. object.author.id

`object has no attribute author`

Note: I implemented login and authentication. So request.user.id gives current user id

Comment: Please also add your models and profile view for more clarity

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The id is not defined here so you cannot use that here, what you should do is handle the user recognition in your Profile view. I am assuming that you would have created a login view etc etc so in your profile view get the user according to the request rather than reversing here with the id